# If $A,B,C$ are matrices and if $A=BC$ why $B^{-1}A=C$ and not $AB^{-1}=C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to know If $A,B,C$ are matrices  and if $A=BC$ why $B^{-1}A=C$ and not $AB^{-1}=C$? I know matrix multiplication is not commutative  but I don't understand why this order is true.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is associative, but not commutative.

Comment: This may appear more obvious if you view $B^{-1}A$ as function composition rather than matrix multiplication.

Comment: @user1551 How is that ?

Comment: Function composition in general is not commutative. E.g. $\sin\cos x\ne\cos\sin x$ and $e^{2x+3}\ne 2e^x+3$. There is no reason to expect it to become commutative merely because the functions concerned are linear (although it is commutative in the scalar case).

Comment: @user1551 I meant how to prove that the multiplication of matrices is a  composition of functions

Comment: This is proved in virtually every introductory linear algebra text. The rule of matrix multiplication arises from compositions of linear maps.

Comment: @user1551 can you recommend me such books ?

Comment: I haven’t any recommendation. Frankly, this is really proved in almost every linear algebra text (e.g. in chap. 3, thm 13 of Hoffman and Kunze or thm 2.7 of Hefferon). Just open a textbook and look at the section on matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A=BC$ and B has an inverse then you are allowed to multiply both sides of the equation by $B^{-1}$. But because matrix multiplication is not *commutative* (it is associative) you have to specify which side you multiply $B^{-1}$ from.

If you multiply it on the right side you get $AB^{-1}=BCB^{-1}$ (note that you cannot, in general, eliminate the $B$ and $B^{-1}$ on the right side, because there is a C in the middle).
If you multiply it on the left side on the other hand you get $B^{-1}A=B^{-1}BC=C$ (your first equation). Note that now the C isn't "blocking" the elimination anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, that you have assumed $A=BC$ and not $A=CB$.

*Case $1$:* Assume that $A=BC$. Then multiply by $B^{-1}$ from the left to obtain $B^{-1}A=B^{-1}BC=I\cdot C=C$.

*Case $2$:* Assume that $A=CB$. Then multiply by $B^{-1}$ from the right to obtain $AB^{-1}=CBB^{-1}=C\cdot I=C$.

If matrix multiplication were commutative, then your assumptions $A=BC$ or $A=CB$ would not be different.